# init constructor error for constant property in c++

Tags: c++

I want to member initializers my const variable and write some code in my constructor outside the class.

#### Compiler error

```
test.cpp:13:4: error: redefinition of 't'
t::t(int n){
   ^
test.cpp:7:5: note: previous definition is here
    t(int n) : num(n),z(n) {}
    ^
test.cpp:13:4: error: constructor for 't' must explicitly initialize the const
      member 'num'
t::t(int n){
   ^
test.cpp:9:15: note: declared here
    const int num;
              ^
test.cpp:21:7: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 't'
    t ob(4);
      ^  ~
test.cpp:4:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not
      viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const t' for 1st argument
class t
```

#### Code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class t
{
public:
    t(int n) : num(n),z(n) {}
private:
    const int num;
    int z;
};

t::t(int n){
    cout<<"TEST";
}

int main()
{
    t ob(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error is because you don't initialize `num` in your *second* constructor (the one implemented outside of your class definition). Providing two implementations for the same constructor is illegal, too, but I suppose your compiler checks that at a later stage.

Comment: If you think it has anything to do with a data member begin `const`, remove the const and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already defined the same constructor twice.
Here:

```
t(int n) : num(n),z(n) {}
```

And here:

```
t::t(int n){
    cout<<"TEST";
}
```

To fix this problem you can change it to:

```
t(int n);
```

And:

```
t::t(int n) : num(n),z(n) {
    cout<<"TEST";
}
```

Or leave the definition inside class if you wish (it will be inline in this case).